# Add UITableView to an existing project: crash when adding array to populate rows

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm adding to a project a TableView populated with countries to choose from. Added the New File (UITableView subclass for iPad+XIB), wrote the trigger IBAction code (editing a textfield if default country is not right), made some connections and the empty table view appears. I have read several tutorials and i cannot make out the problem: **when the array with words loads in - (void)viewDidLoad, the app crashes with the following warning:**

> 2012-05-04 12:34:36.740 pruebaF1[4017:f803] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:6061
>   2012-05-04 12:34:36.741 pruebaF1[4017:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'...

CountryVieWController connections:

**File Owner's connections**
Outlets
dataSource -> File's Owner
delegate ->File's Owner
Referencing Outlets
view -> File's Owner

Code:

```
//  CountryTableVieWController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CountryTableVieWController :      
UITableViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> 

{
    NSMutableArray *countriesArray;
    NSArray *countryArray;
}
@end

//  CountryTableVieWController.m
#import "CountryTableVieWController.h"
#import "pruebaF1SecondViewController.h"

@interface CountryTableVieWController ()
@end

@implementation CountryTableVieWController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{   

    [super viewDidLoad];

    countriesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Austria", @"Italy", @"France",nil];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing the important part, the 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement delegate methods for the UITableView.

Have a look at this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10

I find the easiest way to think of it is that your UITableView is asking your code what should go in the cells. You use these methods to configure your table view and the UITableViewCells within it.

You will need something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    [countriesArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *country  = [countriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = country;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ;) Now the table view displays the list of countries. Followed your suggested tutorial and changed the code to fill in the cells. Unfortunately I got two warnings, both reading the same: "file://localhost/Users/luisprado/Developer/pruebaF1%20copia%202/pruebaF1/CountryTable.xib: warning: Unsupported Configuration: Table View Controller - SELECT COUNTRY view outlet and NIB Name set" There's no "view" to connect, only the table view.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working! Not too sure about your warning. It sounds like you have created a connection in interface builder that is  incorrect.  Perhaps remove connections one at a time and see where the problem is coming from.  If that connection was not a problem, hook it back up and try the next one.